# Hide Control Key Group Value in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-grouping

I have been using SSRS off and on since SQL Server 2008. There are a number of typical SSRS pitfalls and gotchas. One of these I need to go over with some one.

This should be pretty easy for an experienced SSRS resource / expert.

Let me explain the scenario

I have an Invoice Header and Detail. The header contains the Invoice number and InvID. The INVID is the link column for the Invoice detail or the FK in the Invoice detail. I guess that must be pretty obvious to all.

Now I need a simple report that displays Invoices and their items.

For some reasons I do not want to use the Invoice number to group the invoices in the report. I want to use the INVID.

But I want to hide the value of the INVID and display only the invoice number.

In other words the report should look something like follows

```
Invoice Number  Date / Descriptio  Qty Rate Tax Amount
11001           12/52016
                Item No 1          10  10    2  102
                Item No 2          20  10    2  202
```

So on and so forth....

I know this is very easy. Any inputs would be welcome...

Plus any good recommendations in terms of resources for refreshing my knowledge of SSRS

Regards

Comment: If your dataset is getting all the required columns, just add a Parent group by InvID. Detail your dataset structure if you need further help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SSRS you have the flexibility to set the grouping conditions independently of what is displayed in the table. As the others mentioned, add a Row Parent Group by INVID. The group properties should look like this:

[image]

The basic table layout should look something like this:

[image]

So the outer group will repeat for each individual, but display the invoice number. The inner group will repeat for each applicable item.

This should point you in the right direction. I'm not sure of a good resource to direct you to. For me, trial and error has been the most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is bring InvId in in main dataset which you are using in main Tablix, on Tablix you can apply grouping on any field of dataset.